# Convert all PDF files into text in a directory

Tags: python

I just downloaded [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/) to convert PDF files to text. I convert files by executing this command on my terminal

```
python pdf2txt.py -o myOutput.txt simple1.pdf
```

It works fine, now I want to embed that function on my simple Python script. I would like to convert all PDF files on a directory

```
# Lets say I have an array with filenames on it
files = [
    'file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf', 'file3.pdf'
]

# And convert all PDF files to text
# By repeatedly executing pdf2txt.py
for x in range(0, len(files))
    # And run something like
    python pdf2txt.py -o output.txt files[x]
```

I also tried using `os.system` but a blinking window appeared (my terminal). I just wanted to convert all the files on my array to texts.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess

files = [
    'file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf', 'file3.pdf'
]
for f in files:
    cmd = 'python pdf2txt.py -o %s.txt %s' % (f.split('.')[0], f)
    run = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = run.communicate()

    # display errors if they occur    
    if err:
        print err
```

Read the [subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API to help you performing such tasks. [Read the documentation](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/programming.html).